# Which is faster ? nested class or not nested class

Tags: java, inner-classes

this article [The Top Java Memory Problems – Part 2](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2011/12/15/the-top-java-memory-problems-part-2/)
 said that too many class can cause memory leak, so I think its better to create inner class because we can access the private field of the parent instead of passing the field as argument when I instantiate the class.

In terms of memory usage which is better to make nested class or create new java file object (not nested class) ??

Answer (score 2):

The logic in your question is a bit strange: I don't see how being able to access private fields of the enclosing class would reduce the number of classes, and how using nested vs. top-level classes would reduce the number of classes.

Memory usage and performance have nothing to do with the use of nested classes vs. top-level classes. You choose to use one or the other based on design considerations: coupling, encapsulation, etc.

To give you an idea, you could have asked the following question, and it would be very similar to yours in terms of logic and important aspects:

"I've heard that too many cars in a city make the quality of the air very bad, so I think it's better to buy red cars because people can see them better than white ones. But is a red car faster or slower than a white one? Which color should I choose to go faster?"

Comment: red is always quicker

Comment: lol. And also have you read the article shared in the question too? I found that funny, but don't know if it had actually something to do with reality. Or is it just based on hypothetical theories.